# Django No module named 'responsive_images'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Getting the following error when ported Django from 2.7 to 3.6

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>main()
File "manage.py", line 17, in main execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "C:\Django\CampusStore\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
File "C:\Django\CampusStore\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 377, in execute django.setup()
File "C:\Django\CampusStore\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Django\CampusStore\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
File "C:\Django\CampusStore\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
module = import_module(entry)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'responsive_images'
```

Comment: It looks as if you have to install [`django-responsive-images`](https://github.com/ChroneticSoftware/django-responsive-images) in your Python 3 virtual env. It's good practice to keep your installed packages in a `requirements.txt` (or look at tools like pipenv and poetry), so you you can keep track of what packages you need to install for your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure you add the library to your `INSTALLED_APPS` list in settings.py. It's useful to keep in mind the library name as it's downloaded is usually different than it's name in pip. for Example this is installed with `pip install django-responsive-images`, but `responsive_images` is what you should include in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.